# How do I query a database in PHP and return results based on matching user-input?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, user-input

I’m trying to write a PHP script with MySQLi to query a database.

I’d like it if the user-input could be checked against the database and then return a result from the column ‘conjugation’ if the string in the column ‘root’ of the table ‘normal_verbs’ is in the input.

So if the user input is something like "foobar", and the root-column has "foo", I'd like it to see 'foo' in 'foobar' and return that value of 'conjugation' in that row.

I can’t seem to get the query to work like I want it to. The one I'm using below is basically just a placeholder. I don't entirely understand why it doesn't work.

What I’m trying, is this :

```
        function db_connect() {

            static $connection;

            if(!isset($connection)) {
                $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','Verb_Bank');
            }

            if($connection === false) {
                return mysqli_connect_error(); 
            }
            return $connection;
        }

        function db_query($query) {
            $connection = db_connect();
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

            return $result;
        } 

        function db_quote($value) {
                $connection = db_connect();
                return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value) . "'";
            }    
$m= db_query("SELECT `conjugation` from normal_verbs where `root` in (" . $y . ")");
    if($m === false) {
        // Handle failure - log the error, notify administrator, etc.
    } else {
        // Fetch all the rows in an array
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($m)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    }
    print_r ($rows);
```

It’s not giving me any errors, so I think it’s connecting to the database.

EDIT2: I was wrong. I was missing something obvious due to misunderstanding MySQLi and have edited the code accordingly. So the above code does work in that it connects to the database and returns a result, but I'm still stumped on a viable SQL statement to do what I want it to do.

Comment: If those curly quotes are in there you're getting syntax errors, they're in the logs. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You're running the query, but not fetching the data from it with something like `fetch()`

Comment: Have you tried running the query without the where? I would suggest doing SELECT 'conjugation' FROM 'normal_verbs' LIMIT 1.  Assuming your database has data in it, that will tell you if  you are connecting to your actual database.

Comment: Error checking will tell you if you're actually connecting to the database @user2547075

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, but in some cases you can't do that based on hosting set up. Granted, a programmer should have access to that, but still...

Comment: I have never seen an instance where you couldn't employ error checking in the code. If there are hosts out there that disallow error checking they should be out of business @user2547075

Comment: @JayBlanchard I agree. I have seen it though.   Not really a big deal... When I wrote my answer, I hadn't seen yours yet.  If I had, I wouldn't have said anything.

Comment: You are using quotes for table and column names,switch to backticks.Also where is db_query defined?

Comment: @Mihai You're right. My apologies for the omission. I'm not sure how it got left out. I've added it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT 'conjugation' FROM 'normal_verbs' WHERE " . $y . " LIKE CONCAT('%',root,'%')
```

It selects all rows where root contains $y anywhere.

In addition, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please look [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A1-Injection) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Will this select all rows where the `root` table has a substring of $y rather than the entirety of $y?

Comment: Yes, it selects all rows where root is contained in $y. If you want only one result, you can sort them by some parameter and limit them to one.

Comment: Okay, so this more or less worked for me, except that I had to change the "+$y+" to (" . $y . "). Using "+$y+" wasn't doing anything at all. I'd like to know why, but I'm just thrilled that it worked. Thank you!

Comment: That was my error, in PHP you concatinate strings using a . and not a + like in many other languages (e.g. java)

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL Query Like this

```
SELECT `conjugation` from normal_verbs where `root` like '%$y%'
```

Comment: That's giving me a weird error telling me that the variable in my print_r statement is now undefined. 

I put it in as
 $m= db_query("SELECT `conjugation` from normal_verbs where `root` like '%$y%'");
Have I missed some punctuation somewhere or something?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266134/weird-error-in-phpmyadmin-it-is-installed-successfully-but-still-not-working

problem soved